# Difference between preposition and appropriate preposition?

Tags: prepositions

Look the below sentences please:

> Take the book on the table.
> Aeroplane flies over the sky.

On the other hand:

> He died of cancer.
> He  died for country.

Which examples are the appropriate prepositions?

Answer (score 1):

1. *Take the book **on** the table* is OK if you mean "Take the book which is on the table".
2. *An aeroplane flies **in** the sky* (not "over").
3. ***On*** the other hand is OK. See the meaning [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/on-the-other-hand).
4. *He died **of** cancer* is OK. You can also say "he died **from** cancer".
5. *He died **for** his/the country* is also fine. Modify the noun "country" with the article or the possessive pronoun.

Comment: Using "for country" without an article or possessive pronoun is not uncommon, especially when "country" is being invoked as a particularly noble calling.  "For God and for country," is a motto with a long history.