# About Die(d) of and die(d) from

Tags: prepositions

I ma having an uneasiness about the use of the preposition **of** and **from**. I decided to ask when I saw [this ELL question about "He died of cancer" and "He died for country"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/168150/difference-between-preposition-and-appropriate-preposition).

So that, am I correct to understand, according to [this site (EnglishForums.com)](https://www.englishforums.com/English/ToDieOfOrToDieFrom/cjhgj/post.htm), and [this site (Japanese)](http://www.wakaru-english.info/die-of%E3%81%A8die-from%E3%81%AE%E9%81%95%E3%81%84.html), when **of** is used, we refer to the **direct cause** such as cancer, heavy headache (if there were such thing). But when **from** is used, we refer to the (rather) **indirect cause**, such as poverty, weather condition (which is to me questionable.)

Am I correct to understand this in this way?

Comment: It sounds right as a general principle but there are exceptions. People certainly die **of** fatal medical conditions, and of hunger. You can die **of**, **in** or **from** the plague. You can say died **from** poverty or a lightning strike but people are more likely to die **in** poverty and **in** accidents and natural disasters (floods)  and to be killed by lightning rather than to die from it.

Comment: @KT - Look up any of these prepositions on a good dictionary website like [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/of). That alone should be enough to convince you that there is no secret, simple rule that will magically clear up the confusion. Prepositions are too flexible for that. (Note also from those dictionary links that [_from_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/from) can mean "because of" and [_of_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/of) can mean "made from".)

Comment: I could just throw a spanner in the works & add "He died of course' ;-)